# DoubleClick studio thinks I've imported the Enabler component in both my parent and my child asset files

Tags: actionscript-3, document-class

I've just started to work with [DoubleClick Studio](http://studio.doubleclick.com). I've successfully created a Flash expanding ad with CS4 that is mostly scripted and uses the Document class option.

Now for some reason the back end of [DoubleClick Studio](http://studio.doubleclick.com) thinks I've imported the `Enabler` component twice.

I've checked my files numerous of times but can't find the root cause.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that it had to do with importing the main banners document class which in turn imported the `Enabler` component.

Be warned, if you wish to have an interface between your child and parent asset, create an interface if you use strong typed arguments and variables.